# XMLHttpRequest error only when downloading from google play

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, xmlhttprequest, icenium

I've created an app using Icenium Graphite that uses XMLHttpRequest to get data from another site.  If I build the app and download it to my phone from Icenium directly, it works fine on my phone.  However, if I publish it to google play and download it from there, I get the XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 error.

I understand that XMLHttpRequest may cause problems across sites, but why would the same app work ok if I install it one way and not the other?  I'm stumped...

Here's the code:

```
            var url = "https://someremoteserver.com/currencies/exchange_rates";
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging on the device, use jshybugger plugin for the purpose. You can also setup fiddler proxy on your device, if it is a request/response problem, you should be able to find it quickly.